# How to apply filter on Hyperlink column in sharepoint list using rest (with CAML)?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I want to get items in which siteUrl contains value from the variable 'project_url'

```
var project_url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

    var queryText = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='SiteUrl' /><Value Type='URL'>" + project_url + "</Value></Contains></Where>";

    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var webserviceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists(guid'eb0ba220-73e8-428f-b848-92b606aa74d8')/items?$select=ID,Title,MembersId,AccessTYpe,OrganizationalUnitId,SiteUrl"; 

    var queryPayload = {
        'query' : {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
            'ViewXml' : viewXml,
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: webserviceUrl,
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("AllTasks Error -", data);
        }
    });
```

I'm getting this error:

> '"{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hit the `GetItems` endpoint.

Also, change the CAML query to use `BeginsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Modify your code as below:

```
var project_url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

var queryText = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='SiteUrl' /><Value Type='URL'>" + project_url + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";

var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
var webserviceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists(guid'eb0ba220-73e8-428f-b848-92b606aa74d8')/GetItems"; 

var queryPayload = {
    'query' : {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
        'ViewXml' : viewXml,
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: webserviceUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("AllTasks Error -", data);
    }
});
```